# ATX Computer Power Supply Spark in Non-computer Application

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc, atx

I would like to ask for your assistance with using a Silverstone DA1650 Gold computer power supply (you can find more about it here: [Silverstone DA1650 Gold](https://www.silverstonetek.com/en/product/info/power-supplies/DA1650Gold/)) for a non-computer application. In this specific setup, I intend to utilize only the 12V rail, which could potentially draw up to 110A. My plan involves cutting the connectors of 9 EPS 8-pin CPU +12 and GND power connectors and connecting them using solderless crimp terminal connectors (yellow 10-12 AWG). Each of the 3 application inputs will require 3 EPS connectors, each consisting of 4 wires.

**Brief Problem Description:** I encountered some issues and questions during my initial power supply testing. When I connected the Green PS-ON wire to GND, the power supply turned on successfully. I applied a 1A electronic load to measure the 12V rail, and it displayed a stable voltage. However, every time I turn on the power supply, I hear a loud noise resembling a spark. I initially thought it might be a relay, but after multiple attempts, I'm certain it's a spark. Despite this noise, the power supply continues to function. The spark noise is not consistently present, particularly if I turn the power supply on shortly after turning it off. However, when the power supply has been off for an extended period and is turned back on, the spark noise returns.

**My Question:** I'm seeking guidance on identifying and addressing this significant spike or spark issue. My primary concern is whether I can continue using this power supply for testing. Additionally, if there are any questionable choices in my setup or testing approach, I would greatly appreciate any feedback. Thank you in advance for your assistance, and please let me know if you need any additional information.

**Detailed Explanation of My Steps (probably not necessary to read):** Here, I'll outline the steps I took that led to these problems, as there may be some relevance. Initially, I connected the Green PS-ON wire to GND, successfully turning on the power supply. Next, I aimed to measure the 12V line using an electronic load. Initially, I applied a 100mA load to the single pins of the EPS 8-pin CPU +12 and GND, resulting in a measurement of only around 1V. I sought help online and learned that newer computer power supplies often require a larger load to activate the power rails. Consequently, I decided to gradually increase the load, starting with 1A. However, when I applied the load and turned on the power supply, I heard a large spark sound, hence, I turned it off. I suspected that I might have damaged the power supply, so I connected it to an old computer, where it successfully powered up the system, making me think that it is working properly. However, I still occasionally heard the spark noise when turning on the power supply, which concerned me. Why I did not get the 12V before, turned out to be because I did not connect the 6 additional sense wires (originally attached to the EPC 24-PIN motherboard connector) to the power supply. Now, I disconnected it from the computer to test it as before. When I applied a 1A load again, the 12V rail remained stable, but the spark noise persisted. As mentioned before, this spark noise doesn't consistently occur, especially when turning the power supply on shortly after turning it off. However, when the power supply has been off for an extended period and is turned back on, the spark noise reappears, and it's quite noticeable.

Comment: Well, you are misusing the power supply out of it's intended scope of operation and only loading one of the output rails. The supply is not intended to be used like that, as it is not a generic power supply that can be assumed to work in any scenario you put it into. Also it likely is not a spark. Since you are abusing the supply anyway, open the case and observe the sparks, but be careful with live mains circuits, as it is not a safe thing to do.

Comment: @Justme, thank you, but I am aware of it. However, I believe this situation is not as black and white (I hope!). I want to use it for non-computer application, hence, I want to learn the best way to do it.

Comment: There are several things to try: does the spark occur when you have no load? Does the spark occur when you PS-ON through higher resistance to ground or after some delay of being powered?

Comment: @Abel, yes, the spark does occur also when there is no load added. However, I have not tried to add a resistor between PS-ON and GND. I am wondering what is the reasoning for adding a resistor?

Comment: There is no "best" way to do it. Most questions here about using ATX supplies for arbitrary purposes are about why it does not work properly for arbitrary purposes, and it is difficult to give a specific solution that will work with all ATX supplies, or even with your ATX supply. If you want a 12V supply, buy a 12V supply. For ATX supply, you need to add dummy load to all output rails, but the amount of resitance and capacitace required is unknown.

Comment: @Justme, I get your point. Indeed, I would also prefer to use a good switching power supply, but I am in a situation where I need to use this computer power supply. I am just hoping there is someone who might know why there is a spark or some other relevant information.

Comment: @Gabriel It likely does not spark. The sound can be from abnormal operation of the supply as it cannot handle the load you connected. What is the load anyway?

Comment: The reasoning is to try anything that may be differentiating from normal operation.  You may find that this behavior would occur in normal operation too or maybe it wouldn't.  Power it and later give it PS-ON

Comment: @Justme, it might not be a spark, but then I am wondering where the sound comes from. I have to say that I think I have even seen the "spark" through the fan holes, but I cannot be very sure, since I did not want to try to actively make this "spark".  And the load was 1A load when I did notice the "spark", but, for my application, the load would be many smart LED modules and microcontrollers.

Comment: @Abel, alright, that is something I can try. Thanks.

Comment: @Gabriel If it really sparks, the it is damaged and broken and you should not use it at all, you should recycle it. What is the "1A" load, is it resitive, capacitive, inductive, does it vary like is it a car turn signal light turning on-off or some heater behind a thermostat turning on-off or 12V switch mode power supply toggling between 0A and 2A thousands of times per second, or just constant DC 1A stable load?

Comment: @Justme, at this point, the 1A load is just from a lab electronic load, and it does not vary at all. It was in a constant current mode.

Comment: if it's a spark  then you should be able to hear it on an off-station AM radio

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that what you hear is a spark. It is just likely due to abnormal operation of the power supply because it is not used correctly with the way it is assumed to be used.

If it does really spark, it's broken, damaged, and potetially dangerous so you should not use it anyway.

ATX supplies are not intended to power arbitrary loads.

The situation is even worse if you have no load, or only load one output rail. Loading only one rail may cause too high voltages on unused rails and the overvoltage protection circuits may trigger and try to shut down the supply or clamp the overvoltages to safe level, but as there is no load it will quickly be within limits again and the supply resumes normal operation until hitting the overvoltage limits again.

If you do a search here, most questions about ATX supplies being used for custom purposes is why they don't work properly.

You need to at least draw current from all voltage rails, the amount how much is unknown for any general supply or what your supply needs for proper operation. It will also likely help to add capacitive load, to help with certain scenarios you may subject to the power supply, like only drawinh current from 12V load and suddenly disconnecting the load or suddenly reducing the amount of current taken by load.

There are specifications for ATX supplies and they must work properly when used as per the specification requirements. If you don't use the supply as per the specification, the supply does not need to work in your usage properly.

Comment: Thanks, @Justme. You mention that there needs to be a load to other rails, yet, in the datasheet it says that the minimum load is 0A on all the rails. I understand that you give very good pointers to general ATX power supplies, and it might be that all this really applies to my power supply, however, I was hoping to get some more custom suggestions for this specific power supply. I picked it because it says it does not need a load on other rails. And, if it would, I would be very glad to hear how could I customize it for my application.

Comment: Also, I am curious what would be this abnormal operation? Of course, they do not post the schematic of the power supply, but what exactly could cause this noise? I hope that by knowing that, I can understand what I need to improve.

Comment: @Gabriel OK so if you have a power supply that can handle 0A being drawn, that's good. But then it means your supply is broken if it does not work as specified by manufacturer. What is the 12V load you are driving, it may be important to know to explain the behaviour of the supply?

Comment: it seems that the power supply is working. I connected it to a computer and it was able to drive the computer properly, just that there is still this loud spark-type sound almost every time it is turned on. When I noticed this sound, the load was 1A on the 12V rail. I have not tested any larger load than this. And the spark-type sound is still present also without a load, when I turn on the power supply. But, perhaps the key point is that it started to be present once I added this 1A load.

Comment: I think on modern ATX supplies they're designed to have essentially all of the load on the 12v rails with 5 and 3.3v being legacy rails with little to no load.

Comment: @user1850479, yes, that is what I also heard, but why would they then say in the manual that the minimum load is 0A to all the rails?

Answer (score 0):

I would look for loose connections. There may be a bad solder joint at one of the main filter capacitor leads. Loud sparking might result, while output current would go uninterrupted.

Comment: Thanks! However, I do not dare to open up the power supply since the manufacturer highly advises against it. But I see, that again limits my options on how to find the issue.

Comment: What you're doing is already bold. There are safety issues, whenever you open an enclosure. If you don't feel qualified to delve in further, consider finding someone with more experience who can help you.